# Combining Series in Pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, series

I need to combine multiple Pandas `Series` that contain string values. The series are messages that result from multiple validation steps. I try to combine these messages into 1 `Series` to attach it to the `DataFrame`. The problem is that the result is empty.

This is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'b': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']})

index1 = df[df['a'] == 'b'].index
index2 = df[df['a'] == 'a'].index

series = df.iloc[index1].apply(lambda x: x['b'] + '-bbb', axis=1)
series += df.iloc[index2].apply(lambda x: x['a'] + '-aaa', axis=1)

print series
# >>> series
# 0    NaN
# 1    NaN
```

**Update**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'b': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']})

index1 = df[df['a'] == 'b'].index
index2 = df[df['a'] == 'a'].index

series1 = df.iloc[index1].apply(lambda x: x['b'] + '-bbb', axis=1)
series2 = df.iloc[index2].apply(lambda x: x['a'] + '-aaa', axis=1)
series3 = df.iloc[index2].apply(lambda x: x['a'] + '-ccc', axis=1)

# series3 causes a ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
series = pd.concat([series1, series2, series3])
df['series'] = series
print df
```

**Update2**

In this example the indices seem to get mixed up.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'b': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']})

index1 = df[df['a'] == 'a'].index
index2 = df[df['a'] == 'b'].index
index3 = df[df['a'] == 'c'].index

series1 = df.iloc[index1].apply(lambda x: x['a'] + '-aaa', axis=1)
series2 = df.iloc[index2].apply(lambda x: x['a'] + '-bbb', axis=1)
series3 = df.iloc[index3].apply(lambda x: x['a'] + '-ccc', axis=1)

print series1
print
print series2
print
print series3
print

df['series'] = pd.concat([series1, series2, series3], ignore_index=True)
print df
print

df['series'] = pd.concat([series2, series1, series3], ignore_index=True)
print df
print

df['series'] = pd.concat([series3, series2, series1], ignore_index=True)
print df
print
```

This results in this output:

```
0    a-aaa
dtype: object

1    b-bbb
dtype: object

2    c-ccc
dtype: object

   a   b series
0  a  aa  a-aaa
1  b  bb  b-bbb
2  c  cc  c-ccc
3  d  dd    NaN

   a   b series
0  a  aa  b-bbb
1  b  bb  a-aaa
2  c  cc  c-ccc
3  d  dd    NaN

   a   b series
0  a  aa  c-ccc
1  b  bb  b-bbb
2  c  cc  a-aaa
3  d  dd    NaN
```

I would expect only a's in row0, only b's in row1 and only c's in row2, but that's not the case...

**Update 3**

Here's a better example which should demonstrate the expected behaviour. As I said, the use case is that for a given `DataFrame`, a function evaluates each row and possibly returns an error message for some of the rows as a `Series` (some indexes are contained, some are not; if no error returns, the error series is empty).

```
In [12]:

s1 = pd.Series(['b', 'd'], index=[1, 3])
s2 = pd.Series(['a', 'b'], index=[0, 1])
s3 = pd.Series(['c', 'e'], index=[2, 4])
s4 = pd.Series([], index=[])
pd.concat([s1, s2, s3, s4]).sort_index()

# I'd like to get:
#
# 0    a
# 1    b b
# 2    c
# 3    d
# 4    e
Out[12]:
0    a
1    b
1    b
2    c
3    d
4    e
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have found a solution. I hope someone can comment on it...

```
s1 = pd.Series(['b', 'd'], index=[1, 3])
s2 = pd.Series(['a', 'b'], index=[0, 1])
s3 = pd.Series(['c', 'e'], index=[2, 4])
s4 = pd.Series([], index=[])
pd.concat([s1, s2, s3, s4]).sort_index()


df1 = pd.DataFrame(s1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(s2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(s3)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(s4)

d = pd.DataFrame({0:[]})
d = pd.merge(df1, d, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
d = d.fillna('')
d = pd.DataFrame(d['0_x'] + d['0_y'])

d = pd.merge(df2, d, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
d = d.fillna('')
d = pd.DataFrame(d['0_x'] + d['0_y'])

d = pd.merge(df3, d, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
d = d.fillna('')
d = pd.DataFrame(d['0_x'] + d['0_y'])

d = pd.merge(df4, d, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
d = d.fillna('')
d = pd.DataFrame(d['0_x'] + d['0_y'])
print d
```

which returns

```
    0
0   a
1  bb
2   c
3   d
4   e
```

Answer (score 2):

When concatenating the default is to use the existing indices, however if they collide then this will raise a `ValueError` as you've found so you need to set `ignore_index=True`:

```
In [33]:

series = pd.concat([series1, series2, series3], ignore_index=True)
df['series'] = series
print (df)
   a   b  series
0  a  aa  bb-bbb
1  b  bb   a-aaa
2  c  cc   a-ccc
3  d  dd     NaN
```

**EDIT**

I think I know what you want now, you can achieve what you want by converting the series into a dataframe and then merging using the indices:

```
In [96]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'b': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']})

index1 = df[df['a'] == 'b'].index
index2 = df[df['a'] == 'a'].index

series1 = df.iloc[index1].apply(lambda x: x['b'] + '-bbb', axis=1)
series2 = df.iloc[index2].apply(lambda x: x['a'] + '-aaa', axis=1)
series3 = df.iloc[index2].apply(lambda x: x['a'] + '-ccc', axis=1)
# we now don't ignore the index in order to preserve the identity of the row we want to merge back to later
series = pd.concat([series1, series2, series3])
# construct a dataframe from the series and give the column a name
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'series':series})
# perform an outer merge on both df's indices
df.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')

Out[96]:
   a   b  series
0  a  aa   a-aaa
0  a  aa   a-ccc
1  b  bb  bb-bbb
2  c  cc     NaN
3  d  dd     NaN
```

Comment: I don't think this works. `series2` should have added `-aaa` to `index 0` (`df['a'] == 'a'`), not `index 1`.

Comment: Can you update your post to show exactly what you want, it would help to clarify things, at the moment it is confusing to know what you expect

Comment: basically your problem is you have a clash of a non-unique index with the df you are trying to assign the values to, am I right? it looks like what you want is to repeat the a row and have 2 rows, one with a-aaa and another with a-ccc, can you confirm

Comment: This is what I'd like to achieve, but with `series = pd.concat([series1, series2, series3])` you run into the same problem I had initially: the `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` (it's just not exposed in this example).

Comment: @orange sorry are you using my new modified method now or not? you should be able to create a dataframe from the concatenated series and merge this back to your original dataframe

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't throw a `ValueError` exception this time, as it did in the first example, but in your last example, you get `index0` twice. I would like these two merged together (i.e. string-concatenated). I realise that my examples are a bit convoluted and provided another update.

Answer (score 0):

how about concat?

```
s1 = df.iloc[index1].apply(lambda x: x['b'] + '-bbb', axis=1)
s2 = df.iloc[index2].apply(lambda x: x['a'] + '-aaa', axis=1)


s = pd.concat([s1,s2])
print s

1    bb-bbb
0    a-aaa
dtype: object
```

Comment: Sorry, I have to retract. Getting a ValueError (see updated example).